# Problems with QDateEdit delegate

Tags: qt

I need to have the ability to edit date in QTableView, so i implemented QItemDelegate:

```
#include "dateeditdelegate.h"

DateEditDelegate::DateEditDelegate(QObject *parent) :
    QItemDelegate(parent)
{
}

QWidget *DateEditDelegate::createEditor(QWidget *parent, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    QDateEdit * editor = new QDateEdit(parent);
    return editor;
}

void DateEditDelegate::setEditorData(QWidget *editor, const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    QDateEdit * dateEdit = static_cast<QDateEdit*>(editor);
    dateEdit->setDate(index.model()->data(index).toDate());
}

void DateEditDelegate::setModelData(QWidget *editor, QAbstractItemModel *model, const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    QDateEdit * dateEdit = static_cast<QDateEdit*>(editor);
    model->setData(index, dateEdit->dateTime().toTime_t());
}

void DateEditDelegate::updateEditorGeometry(QWidget *editor, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    editor->setGeometry(option.rect);
}
```

And also i reimplemented QSqlRelationalTableModel:

```
QVariant TblModel::data(const QModelIndex &item, int role) const
{
    if(item.column() == this->fieldIndex("add_date")){
        return QVariant(QDateTime::fromTime_t(QSqlQueryModel::data(item, role).toUInt()).date());
    }
    return QSqlQueryModel::data(item, role);
}
```

But as result I get [this](http://vk.cc/2z9piw)

These fields are editable, but after editing new values are not saved (i can change any field to "01.01.2015", but after pressing Enter it reverts to "03.04.14"). Also, i can't understand, why do these checkboxes appear.

Comment: Hm, but you always set the same data, in `TblModel::data()`. Did you implement `setData()` model function as well?

Comment: @vahancho Hm, i don't understand, why should i implement setData()?

Comment: Because you want to edit your model, and call `model->setData(index, dateEdit->dateTime().toTime_t());`

Comment: Ok. i'll do it. But what's with checkboxes?

Comment: The same for them, but handle checkboxes with `Qt::CheckStateRole`

Comment: I mean, they should *not* appear.

Comment: It also says: `QSqlQuery::value: not positioned on a valid record` while I'm trying to change values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your main problem is that you don't understand the whole MVC framework that Qt provides.

You don't need a custom delegate. The default one, `QItemDelegate` already knows how to create editors for date/time data.

The solution to the first part of your problem lies with re-implementing the `data()` of the model.

`QSqlQueryModel` is explicitly defined as a read-only model. If you wish to edit data, you will need to create your own mechanism for storing and editing the underlying data, which you will change by re-implementing the `setData()` function.

You need to cater for the different roles if you are going to get the results you want. For your purposes, you need to implement for `Qt::DisplayRole`, `Qt::EditRole` and `Qt::TextAlignmentRole`

`Qt::DisplayRole` is what gets displayed on the view and the most usual format is `QString`.

`Qt::EditRole` is the data that gets given to the delegate so that it can create an appropriate editor widget and give it the correct data.

`Qt::TextAlignmentRole` is used to tell the view how to align the data returned from the call with `Qt::DisplayRole`.

```
QVariant TblModel::data(const QModelIndex &item, int role) const{

    if(item.column() == this->fieldIndex("add_date")){
        if (role == Qt::TextAlignmentRole){
            return QVariant(Qt::AlignLeft | Qt::AlignVCenter);
        }

        QDateTime dateTime = QDateTime::fromTime_t(QSqlQueryModel::data(item, role).toUInt());
        if (role == Qt::DisplayRole){
            return dateTime.toString("dd.MM.yyyy");
        }
        if (role == Qt::EditRole){
            return dateTime.date();
        }
    }
    return QSqlQueryModel::data(item, role);
}
```

If you want your data to be editable, you need to use a different base model than `QSqlQueryModel`. The next part you have not implemented is to change the data in the model. You do this by reimplementing the `setData()` function.

```
bool TblModel::setData(QModelIndex const &index, QVariant const &value, int role){
    if (!index.isValid() || role == Qt::EditRole){
        return false;
    }

    if (index.column() == fieldIndex("add_date")){
        // modify the underlying data

        if (validEdit){
            emit dataChanged(index, index); // signal to the view that the item needs to be redrawn
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: What means "modify the underlying data"?

Comment: It means modifying the structures where you are storing your data. You cannot modify QSqlQueryModel so you need to extract the data from the database and store it yourself.

Comment: OK, I have done this, but now I have another problem: `QSqlRelationalTableModel::setData` don't work, it returns `true`, but nothing saved(and nowhere).

Comment: As I said before, you must modify the underlying data yourself. Where are you storing the data? Change it there.